# wampp or xampp: how to upgrade to mysql 6?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, wamp

I'm on windows xp pro, I've been told to use `mysql2 gem` in my ruby on rails app. `mysql 2 gm` wont work unless you have mysql 6 installed. wamp and xampp do not have mysql 6 included in their latest versions! so how to install mysql 6...I'm using xampp and I do not want to install mysql then apache then php then phpmyadmin, i want to use something that has the whole package like wamp or xampp so I'm wondering if you know how to upgrade to mysql 6

and one more thing, is mysql 6 widely supported? i want to try my app on some shared hosting so i don't want to install `mysql2` for development and `mysql` in production just because the hosting providers doesn't support mysql 6

When i run `rake db:create` i see:

```
rake aborted! incorrect mysql client library version! this gem was compiled for 6.0.0 but the client library is 5.5.12
```

Comment: if you cannot answer the question, just tell me if mysql6 is widely supported or not, so that i wouldn't waste my time fixing the problem!

Comment: What did you do to solve this?

Comment: @Railsbeginner please read my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have solved this error by downloading [the zipped version of mysql Connector/C 6.0.2 for 32 bit][4] and copying `libmysql.dll` from `mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32-vs2005\lib`

to `C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.2\bin`

Comment: great! just needed to add mysql connector's dll to railsinstaller

Answer (score 0):

mysql 5.5.20 is the latest stable version...i use 5.5.0 and 5.1 and mysql2 works fine